# How do I kill Siri

Tags: macos, siri

In other words, which file causes Siri to stop changing PID?

Even though I force process to quit, it will spawn again.[image]

Comment: In the voice of HAL 9000 from 2001: A Space Oddesy, I'm sorry FullMetalFist, I cannot allow you to do that. :)

Answer (score 1):

Mac Preferences -> Siri -> uncheck Enable Siri checkbox. -> Reboot.

This will stop Siri from running.

To answer your question about changing PIDs, PID is a Process ID. Anytime a new process is created, it'll always change its ID to a new one. There is no changing this as it's a flow of how processes and multithreading work.